# Adding to an existing element in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do you add one (+1) to a cell with an existing element in an numpy array? I have a 21x23 zeros array and I want to count occurences by adding one .

```
for r in holdscore:
    results = np.zeros(shape=(21, 23))
    if one_game(r) < 21:
        results[r,one_game(r)] += 1
    if one_game(r) > 21:
        results[r, 22] += 1
```

Comment: Don't really do `numpy`, but what you seem to be doing is that you are resetting `results` for every iteration. Try putting it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing correctly. The problem is that you forget about the old array and make a new one every time through the loop.

Move this statement:

```
results = np.zeros(shape=(21, 23))
```

outside the loop:

```
results = np.zeros(shape=(21, 23))
for r in holdscore:
    if one_game(r) < 21:
        results[r,one_game(r)] += 1
    if one_game(r) > 21:
        results[r, 22] += 1
```

so it doesn't happen on every iteration.

Comment: Damn, I was going to put this as an answer, but I wasn't sure. Glad someone else was though, +1.